# RestKit serialization of Core Data relationship

Tags: ios, json, serialization, restkit

I have a CoreData backed contact object that has a one-to-many relationship to both email and phone_number entities. All objects mentioned here are NSManagedObjects.

The phone_number and email entity both just have one attribute which is an NSString* representing the phone_number and email respectively.

Currently when I serialize the object I get something like

```
    {contacts: 
        [{"name":"person1", 
        "emails":[{"email":"email1@email.com"}, {"email":"email2@email.com"}], 
        "phone_numbers":[{"number":"1111111111"}, {"number":"2222222222"}]},
        {"name":"person2", 
        "emails":[{"email":"email1@email.com"}, {"email":"email2@email.com"}],
        "phone_numbers":[{"number":"3333333333"}, {"number":"4444444444"}]}]
    }
```

I would like to serialize to something like this

```
    {contacts: 
        [{"name":"person1", 
        "emails":["email1@email.com","email2@email.com"], 
        "phone_numbers":["1111111111", "2222222222"]},
        {"name":"person2", 
        "emails":["email1@email.com", "email2@email.com"],
        "phone_numbers":["3333333333", "4444444444"]}]
    }
```

notice how the list of "emails" and "phone_numbers" are just a list of strings, without an associated key for each phone_number/email

my current mapping code is (the phone_number mapping code is exactly the same as the Email mapping code)

```
    @implementation Email

    @dynamic email;
    @dynamic contact;

    + (void)emailRKObjectMapping {
      RKManagedObjectMapping* emailMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Email" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore];
      [emailMapping mapKeyPath:@"email" toAttribute:@"email"];
      [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:emailMapping];

      //Serialization mapping for Contact class
      [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping":[emailMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[Email class]];
     }
    @end
```

The Contact mapping code that has a relationship pointing to the Email/Phone Number

```
    @implementation Contact
    ...
    @dynamic emails;
    @dynamic phoneNumbers;
    ...

    + (void)contactRKObjectMapping {
      RKManagedObjectMapping* contactMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore];

      ...
      ...

      [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:contactMapping];

      //Serialization mapping for Contact class
      RKManagedObjectMapping* contactSerializationMapping = [contactMapping copy];
      [contactSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"emails" toRelationship:@"emails" withMapping:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[Email class]]];
      [contactSerializationMapping mapKeyPath:@"phone_numbers" toRelationship:@"phoneNumbers" withMapping:[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider objectMappingForClass:[PhoneNumber class]]];
      [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[contactSerializationMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[Contact class]];
    }
```

To me it seems silly to have to send the key "phone_number" or "email" up for every phone number and email in the array of emails and phone_numbers. I just want an easy way to serialize to an array of strings with one key.

Thanks for your help!